# Difference between IE8 & EmulateIE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, meta-tags

I added a compatibility mode meta tag at the top of the header to force the browser to render in IE8 mode.
It is working with IE10 & IE11 but not with IE9.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" />
```

Can any one explain what I am doing wrong here? Should I use content="IE=EmulateIE8" instead of content="IE=IE8"?

Comment: The `Understanding legacy document modes' [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) should provide some insight.

Comment: can have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/dd835379.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Well, following the links provided by `Carpetsmoker` and `www.sblog.in` I end up with a broad answer and improved with more sources. This is what I found:

Starting with the [IE8 Beta2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx) there is a new way to make you site compatible. This way is know as `IE=EmulateIE7` (It supports newer browser too like in your question).

In the same link was provided this:

> **IE=7**: Display in IE7 Standards mode.
>
> **IE=EmulateIE7**: Display standards
>   DOCTYPEs in IE7 Standards mode; Display quirks DOCTYPEs in Quirks
>   mode.

So basically when you are specifying the version like `IE=8` you are make it clear that the page needs to use the most advanced standards that browser use to have and not exactly the wayt it would render.

In the other way if you specify `IE=EmulateIE8` the browser will make a decision if it will render with the version standards or with quirks mode. So if `IE8` use to render `www.example.com` with its quirks mode, `IE11` receiving `IE=EmulateIE8` will make the same choice.

In the compatibility perspective the proper way to make a page backward compatible you choose use the *Emulate* version always.

I've found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx) very useful chart demonstrating the path `IE` uses to determine witch `Document Mode` it uses and you can see where the decisions change because the **Emulate** version of the tag.

**P.S.**

I won't paste the image directly here because it too large to fits in this Q&A width.