# Run VBScript in WebBrowser control feature emulation set to IE 11

Tags: c#, vbscript, internet-explorer-11, browser-feature-detection

We have a web browser application that needs to run in emulation mode of IE 11.
IE 11 no longer supports VB Script, hence few legacy pages have broken.

Any ideas to get it working without much change. 
We will be retiring VB script usage soon .

But we need a short gap fix to get through with it now.

Comment: can you set the compatiblilty mode to ie10?

Comment: Thanks for replying Daniel. Yes, tried it but didn't work :(

Comment: what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483782/vbscript-support-in-internet-explorer-11

Comment: yes had went through it before posting .. hta is one thing which can be tried out . hopefully it works..

Comment: hey Daniel, thanks a lot buddy. Adding compatibility tag worked. Needed some effort to understand the prerequisites and how it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the above using meta compatibility tag in at start of html:
`<!DOCTYPE html> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>`

IE="8" works too, IE = 9 and 10 not so much. 
Hope it helps some one in the future.

If you are ending up using a xhtml page please use:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

[to know the difference about IE=7 and IE=EmulateIE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987260/difference-between-ie8-emulateie8)